# Independent samples t test when you don't know what to expect

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Say I want to compare the means of two groups in SPSS (men and women). The particular thing is that for these groups in the context that I'm researching, there are no theories to formulate a decisive hypothesis. So that means I don't know beforehand whether one group will have a higher means than the other or if they will be the same.

If I HAD to formulate a hypothesis, I would say that “H1: the mean of group A is NOT equal to the mean of group B”: so a two-sided hypothesis.
Now, in the results I see that the two sided p-value is higher than 0,05, so I would say that I keep the nulhypothesis that there is insufficient evidence to say there is a difference between both groups.

BUT: I see that the one-sided p-value is less than 0,05. So what do I do? Can I still say that there is a significant difference between both groups?

Comment: You formulate an alternative hypothesis (1- or 2-sided) before you see the results of testing and even the means themselves. So, since your decision was 2-sided, stay on it.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Why are you formulating any hypothesis at all?  It sounds like you might be trying to *discover* something rather than test it.